# double[] collection to string

Tags: c#, linq

Basically I have a collection of sizes..
Collection

```
12,12
23,23
34,34
23,65
12,3
```

etc..

I am trying to take these and compare the 2 values and return a string..

If the values are the same, then return only 1 of the numbers, if they are different then return both..

Example..

```
  new string.. 12, 23, 34, 23x65, 12x3
```

This is the code I wrote which obviously is not the result I am trying to get..

```
 List<double[]> oSize_list = _orderedCollection
    .Select(t => new double[] { t.psizeW, t.psizeH })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What is a type of `_orderedCollection`?

Comment: You need to change the return type of your `Func` for your [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To turn an array of `(psizeW, psizeH)` pairs into an array of strings, with the string format depending on whether `psizeW` equals `psizeH`, you could:

```
var result = _orderedCollection
    .Select(t => t.psizeW == t.psizeH ? 
            string.Format("{0}", t.psizeW) :
            string.Format("{0}x{1}", t.psizeW, t.psizeH))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: wow, that's pretty simple when I see it.. Thanks.. Unsure why I could not think of this my self..

Comment: Is there any benefit to use var instead of string?

Comment: The advantage of `var` is you don't have to mentally parse the type when you read the code.  It's still a static type (inferred at compile time)

Comment: If you _know_ that you intend to get a `List<string>` (or `IEnumerable<string>`) out of the Linq calls, then it can be worthwhile to explicitly declare that there rather than use `var`. Readers won't have to parse your Linq logic to know what the result is you intended to get, and you won't accidentally change your Linq to create incompatible result with the rest of the code that depends upon `result`.

Answer (score 7):

```
List<string> oSize_list = _orderedCollection
    .Select(t => t.psizeW == t.psizeH ? t.psizeW.ToString() : string.Format("{0}x{1}", t.psizeW, t.psizeH))
    .ToList();
```

This should accomplish your goal

Comment: This has 1 less `String.Format`

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to do is to create a function to do your comparison and use it in your linq query.

```
    private string SizeToString(int a, int b)
    {
        if (a == b)
        {
            return a.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return String.Format("{0}x{1}", a, b);
        }
    }


    var stringSizes = from t in _orderedCollection
                      select SizeToString(t.psizeW, t.psizeH);
```

If you're always wanting to do this for the same object type, you could make SizeToString take a size object instead of the individual dimensions.

Comment: +1 The function and query syntax make this easier to read.  The string concatenation (with a character too!) feels less clear than its `string.Format()` counterpart.

Comment: In efficient code I'd use string.format, but I whip those pluses off faster and find them easier to read.  Probably spent too many years as a VBA programmer.  I can update it.

Comment: The function format is especially useful if you're going to end up doing this conversion in more than one place.